# Android: Eclipse keeps Build Workspace, endless loop

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, workspace

I just came across this problem yesterday and is still occurring today. This happened after after I changed the package name of my project. Everything works fine, no errors but the eclipse keeps building workspace, goes from 60 % - 73 % and goes to sleep than repeats. Any suggestions? I also updated the Android developer tools to the latest versions.

I seem to have narrowed down the problem to a library that I am referencing in my main project.  This is because When I import the projects separately this endless loop does not occur. Also every 30 seconds I am able to capture this brief error which says "This project was not built due to "Coult not delete bin/classes/com" Fix this problem then try refreshing this project."

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have tried deleting the bin folders and restarting but it does not work....

Answer (score 1):

- goto project->clean
- check your project name in androidXML
- remove the library that u added and then add it back again
- debug and run ....

it works with me .